# Confirmation email from devise on rails3 using gmail not arriving

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gmail, ssl, devise

I've set the following up.

```
----------------------
config/environments/development.rb
----------------------
 29   ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
 30   ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
 31   ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
 32  
 33   ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
 34     :enable_starttls_auto => true,  #this is the important stuff!
 35     :address        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
 36     :port           => 587,
 37     :domain         => 'foo.com',
 38     :authentication => :plain,
 39     :user_name      => '---@---.---',
 40     :password       => '---'
 41   }
```

However when devise sends the confirmation email webbrick prints out
the email in the log with no error but the email does not end up
in my inbox or spam inbox.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
I now get

    Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. x13sm2646038bki.0
```

):

I found that

```
----------------------
config/environments/development.rb
----------------------
 17   # Don't care if the mailer can't send
 18   config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
```

Had been set higher up in the config file. However what is this about issuing a STARTTLS command?

SOLUTION:

```
----------------------
config/environments/development.rb
----------------------
 26   require 'tlsmail' #key but not always described
 27   Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
 28  
 29   ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
 30   ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
 31   ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
 32  
 33   ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
 34     :enable_starttls_auto => true,  #this is the important stuff!
 35     :address        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
 36     :port           => 587,
 37     :domain         => 'xtargets.com',
 38     :authentication => :plain,
 39     :user_name      => '-------',
 40     :password       => '-------'
 41   }
 42
```

Brad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the very same problem; in my case was due to a bug (Net::SMTP does not how to speak TLS, which is required by gmail) and I solved it as explained [here](http://dev.nuclearrooster.com/2007/12/12/creating-a-ruby-gem-for-smtp_tls/).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than turning off SSL cert verification globally, you can pass an extra parameter to smtp_settings:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => 'smtp.example.com',
  :port                 => '25',
  :domain               => 'example.com',
  :user_name            => 'someone@example.com',
  :password             => 'secret',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :openssl_verify_mode  => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
}
```

You may also need to `require 'openssl'` to get that constant.

This solution also works with `Pony`, if you include `:openssl_verify_mode` in the `:via_options` hash.

Comment: You seem to have an extra trailing comma there at the end.