# Devise with Rails sending mails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, devise

I am a newbie to sending mails through rails. I have implemented devise in my project and now I want to send a welcome email and/or a password-reset email. What changes do I need to make in Devise views? 
No errors are displayed, but still I don't receive any email.

I have followed the links specified below and finally my devise.rb, development.rb and production.rb files are as follows:

```
 devise.rb 

 config.mailer_sender = "abc@gmail.com"

development.rb

config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"


  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings ={
 :enable_starttls_auto => true,
 :address            => 'smtp.gmail.com',
 :port               => 587,
 :tls                => true,
 :domain             => 'gmail.com',
 :authentication     => :plain,
 :user_name          => 'abc@gmail.com',
 :password           => '123456' 
 }

 production.rb
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'gmail.com' }

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
   config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors =false 
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :address            => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port               => 587,
  :tls                  => true,
  :domain             => 'gmail.com',
  :authentication     => :plain,
  :user_name          => 'abc@gmail.com',
  :password           => '123456' 
 }
```

Comment: possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794669/confirmation-email-from-devise-on-rails3-using-gmail-not-arriving

Comment: Are you testing in development only? because you have `perform_deliveries` set to false there

Comment: hey thnx @Andrei that solved my problem too :)

Comment: I didn't think that would be the problem, that's why I added my answer as a comment; I'll put it as an answer so you can close it. Glad to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to send an email using rails in `development` environment, you'll see that in the configuration file for `development`, there is a line `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false` which specifies whether mail will actually be delivered.

When you create a new rails project that parameter is automatically set to `false`, and if you want to actually send an email in development mode, you must (among other things) set that parameter to `true`